# Swift 2: Rotating tires

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Looking for a method to rotate two sprites that are tires for a car.

Tried to use RotateByAngle, but that makes the tire go out of it's position to go in a circle much bigger then the car. I want the tire to stay in the exact same position and rotate 360 degrees forever. Like a normal tire should.

```
let wheel = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:1)
playerWheelleft.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(wheelSpeed))
```

If there are better solutions to this problem then to use rotateByAngle please let me know.

The reason the tire sprite is not the center is because i use SKPhysicsJoint to connect the two tires to the rest of the car

```
  var playerJoint = SKPhysicsJointPin.jointWithBodyA(player.physicsBody!, bodyB:playerWheelleft.physicsBody!, anchor:player.position)
    self.physicsWorld.addJoint(playerJoint)


    playerJoint = SKPhysicsJointPin.jointWithBodyA(player.physicsBody!, bodyB:playerWheelright.physicsBody!, anchor:player.position)
    self.physicsWorld.addJoint(playerJoint)
```

I tried to remove the code that connects the tires with the rest of the car and then the rotation works great?

How can I make the tires the center rotation point?

```
let playerWheelsTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "playerWheel")
    playerWheelleft = SKSpriteNode(texture: playerWheelsTexture)
    playerWheelleft.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 50, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 320)
    playerWheelleft.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: playerWheelsTexture, size: playerWheelsTexture.size())


let wheelSpeed = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:0.5)
    playerWheelleft.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(wheelSpeed))
    playerWheelright.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(wheelSpeed))
```

Comment: It sounds like the rotation point is not the center of `playerWheelleft`

Comment: @0x141E Do you know how i can solve that?

Comment: I suggest you post the code that defines `playerWheelleft`

Comment: @0x141E Okey, I updated the question now

Comment: Perhaps you should consider adding the wheels as children of the car and set the `pinned` property to `true` instead of connecting them with joints. You can then spin the wheels by setting the `angularVelocity` or applying torque or angular impulse.